# is this matrix is diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given matrix A. The question is if matrix A is diagonalizable matrix for k = 0?

\begin{bmatrix}
k & -k & k \\
-k & k & -k \\
k & -k & k
\end{bmatrix}

My solution is:
find the eigenvalues by solving the characteristic equation |A - λI| = 0
$$det = (k-λ)((k-λ)(k-λ) - (-k)(-k)) - (-k)(-k(k-λ) + k(-k))
    = (k-λ)((k-λ)^2 - k^2) + k^2((k-λ) - k)
    = (k-λ)(k^2 - 2kλ + λ^2 - k^2) + (k^3 - k^2λ - k^3 + k^2)
    = (k-λ)(- 2kλ + λ^2) + k^2 - k^2λ
    = -2kλ^2 + λ^3 + 2k^2λ - λ^2 + k^2 - k^2λ
    = -2kλ^2 + λ^3 + k^2λ - λ^2 + k^2
    = λ^3 - 2kλ^2 + (k^2 + k^2)λ
    = λ^3 - 2kλ^2 + 2k^2λ$$

for $$λ= 0: λ^3 - 2*0*λ^2 + 2*0^2*λ = λ^3 = 0$$

Then its a matrix 3x3 of zeros multiplied in vector x,y,z and hence this matrix is not diagonalizable. Am I right here?

Comment: Check your computation of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: For $k=0$, the matrix is just the zero matrix, which is obviously diagonalizable. So, perhaps, you mean $k \ne 0$, and the inline equation below the "for" should then be changed to $λ= 0: λ^3 - 2*k*λ^2 + 2*k^2*λ = 0$.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the null space of the matrix (for $k \ne 0$) consists of $3$-dimensional vectors for which the second component is equal to the sum of the other two.

Comment: @NDB is right. The first line of your determinant calculation already missed the entire $k((-k)(-k)-(k-\lambda)(k))$ term for the third minor (and there seems to be a sign issue in your second minor term as well).

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is a multiple of $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 
 1\\
-1 & 1 & -1\\
1 &-1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ The matrix $A$ is symmetric, therefore diagonalizable. Moreover the rank of $A$ is equal $1$ as the span of the columns is one dimensional. Therefore the eigenvalues are $0$ (a double eigenvalue) and $3$ (as the trace is equal $3).$ The eigenvectors (orthogonal to each other) are $(1,-1,1)$ and $(1,2,1),(1,0,-1).$